# postgresql. full text search for queries with misprints

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

Is it possible to implement full text search using postgresql when queries can be with misprints?
I couldn't find it in manual.

Comment: Are you looking for typo / transcription-error resistant full-text search? If so, no, FTS doesn't currently support fuzzy or "similar" searching.

Comment: auto-correct your queries before using them. use a spell-checker.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by misprint.

If you are looking for fuzzy string matching, [the `fuzzystrmatch` extension is what you want](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html).

`fuzzystrmatch` is a module, you must "install" it by running :

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

This way of installing extensions exists since PostgreSQL 9.1.

For previous versions, you needed to run the sql script in the contrib dir for that extension against your database.

Comment: Ah, knew I'd seen a blog about it somewhere. There's a similar example here using trigrams: http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/09/06-pg_trgm-suggestions